# Selenium button is found but click is not performed

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to click on a button identified by the xpath but it doesn't work.

However there is no error on the click action. The button is found, but the click action is not performed.

I have tried the following solutions:

**Solution 1**

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn_M9pg_']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(elem);
actions.click(elem);
Action a = actions.build();
a.perform();
```

**Solution 2**

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn_M9pg_']")).click();`

Can you help me please? Thank you very much!

**update 1**

Please find below the logs. the element button by id `btn_D_Ir_` is not found because the previous click (`//button[@id='btn_M9pg_']`) is not performed.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.id: btn_D_Ir_ (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
    at TripleA.TFT_508.main(TFT_508.java:219)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#btn_D_Ir_"}
  (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.87)
```

Comment: please add stack trace. what is shown in the logs?

Comment: Thanks i added the logs in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try use *WebDriverWait*, like this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@id='btn_M9pg_']"))).click();
```

And you can click via js, like this:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("btn_M9pg_")); 
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is not resolved, we have the same error.

Comment: @cheikh could you add html with a button?

Comment: <button id="btn_M9pg_" type="button" class="btn" onclick="$SF({'form':'form','diff':true,'param':'flow-action=simulateOrder',},this);">Check</button>

Comment: Try this: ```WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("btn_M9pg_"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);```